# Manipulate the Clipboard in C on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos

How do you copy text to the clipboard in C or with a Command-Line command?

Answer (score 5):

pbcopy and pbpaste are your friends on the command line:

```
echo 'send' | pbcopy
pbpaste > receive.txt
```

Take a look at the [Pasteboard Manager Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Pasteboard_Reference/Reference/reference.html) and [guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Pasteboard_Prog_Guide/paste_intro/paste_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001439) for details on doing this in C.

Comment: For reading this answer nearly a decade later, the links are dead.